# how to show animation loading.gif when click submit

Tags: jquery

How to show animation loading... when click submit

```
<form id="submit">
  <textarea name="update"id="update"maxlength="500"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="saveResult" value="Save All Data" />
  <div id="displayResult"></div>
```

Show animation loading when submit form

```
$("#saveResult").click(function() {
    var firstname = $("#update").val();
    lastname = $("#lname").val();
    $.post("re.asp", {
        update2: firstname
    }, function(data) {
        $("#displayResult").html(data);
    });
    $('#update').val('');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show an element before the call o `$.post` and inside post, in the callback, hide it again when the data arrives.

```
//jQuery
$("#saveResult").click(function () {
     var firstname = $("#update").val();
     lastname = $("#lname").val();

     //showing your loading element
     $('.loading').show();

     $.post("re.asp", {
         update2: firstname
     }, function (data) {
         $("#displayResult").html(data);

        //hidding your loading element
         $('.loading').hide();
     });
     $('#update').val('');
     return false;
 });
```

Of course, you would need to creating an element with the loading class:

```
//HTML
<div class="loading">
    <img src="loadingGif.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

It should be hidden by default:

```
//CSS 
.loading{
    display:none;
}
```